# Understanding i.i.d. random variables from product measure space perspective

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I have a very weak background in measure theory, and I am having some troubles understanding i.i.d. random variables from a measure theoretic perspective.

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on a probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$. I have seen that some authors write "$X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are $n$ independent copies of $X$", which I understand as $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables having the same distribution as that of $X$. 
I found that the most intuitive way to construct an i.i.d. sequence to me is to define $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ on a product measure space $(\Omega^n, \mathcal{F}^n,P^n)$.

Here is how I understand this construction.
When we say something like $(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = (X_1(\omega),\ldots, X_n(\omega))$, this $\omega$ belongs to $\Omega^n$, whereas when we consider $X(\tau)$, this $\tau$ is in $\Omega$. So $\omega$ and $\tau$ belong to different spaces unless $n=1$. Thus, $X_i$ and $X$ are completely different functions (defined on different domains $\Omega^n$ and $\Omega$). So, $X_i$ is not a copy of $X$ as a function, but they just have the same distribution.

Moreover, as $n$ changes, the probability triple $(\Omega^n, \mathcal{F}^n,P^n)$ also changes accordingly. Hence, for example, if we consider $(X_1(\gamma), X_2(\gamma))$ and $(X_1(\sigma),X_2(\sigma),X_3(\sigma))$, $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ live in different spaces, $\Omega^2$ and $\Omega^3$. So, the random variable $X_1$ in the pair $(X_1, X_2)$ and $X_1$ in the triple $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ are also different functions (defined on different domains), but having the same distribution, and denoted by the same notation.

Is this understanding correct? I am confused since the dependency on $n$ does not seem to be explicitly specified in most cases, and they seem to use the same notations $\omega$, $\Omega$, $X_i$, etc. everywhere.

Many thanks.